# How cut right block layout by viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a task for hide vertical scroll bar and cut picture from right block until picture will have half size. After that show scroll bar

[image: design]

Comment: Maybe you need 'overflow: hidden'. Post your code, or jsfiddle, and you can recibe more help.

Comment: Please provide code to allow us to reproduce your issue and show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oo9kkagu/

Comment: Thanks @korvinko it would probably be a good idea to add the Fiddle and code to your question. :)

Comment: Maybe you need to reduce the width in '.l-top-content' element, exclude the padding (80px in left and right). Would be 1200 - 160px. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do this differently...

Instead of putting the image in its own element, I would instead put the image as the background of the container with the text.  Position the background image enough from the left edge so that the text doesn't overlap it.  Let the text container extend all the way to the right edge of the screen.  Image will automatically crop from the right edge it there is not enough screen space.

```
<div style="background-image:url(laptop-img.png); background-position: left:400px">
  ... text and form ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for good solution. Should I have max-width in container to cut right side?

Comment: I just forget to setup max, min width for container. But your suggestion simplify html. Thanks again.